# C programming: dynamically allocated memory for string and sqlite3_open doesn't work together

Tags: c, sqlite, realloc

I am a bit confused about this little program:

When I run it, it loops till i = 999 and then gives "corrupted double linked list". In func1, printf is showing that str is like str2, but in main str is empty.

I observed that the program is working well if I do one of two things:

1. put in str2 a small string like "Hello".
2. comment the code related to database (sqlite3_open and sqlite3_close);

Thank you!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sqlite3.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

sqlite3 *conn;

void func1 (char* str)
{
   char str2[3000];
   strcpy (str2, "dawNUkjhkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkdwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwaauhfuiahfsuehusehfseihfseifjhselfjslkejfklsejfksejksejfeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeejjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjUkjhkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkdwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwaauhfuiahfsuehusehfseihfseifjhselfjslkejfklsejfksejksejfeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeejjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjUkjhkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkdwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwaauhfuiahfsuehusehfseihfseifjhselfjslkejfklsejfksejksejfeeeeeeejjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjdawfa");

   // strcpy (str2, "Hello\n");

   str = (char*) realloc (str, sizeof (char) * (strlen (str2) * 2));
   strcat (str, str2);

   printf ("func1:  %s\n", str);

}

int main ()
{
    int dataBaseResult;
    char* str = malloc (sizeof (char));

    /* open database */
    dataBaseResult = sqlite3_open ("magazin.db", &conn);
    if (dataBaseResult != 0)
    {
       fprintf (stderr, "Problem %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg (conn));
    }
    else 
    {
       printf ("Opened succesfully!\n");
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
       printf ("main:  %d\n", i);           

       strcpy (str, "");

       func1 (str);

       printf ("main:  %s\n", str);
    }


    /* close database */
    sqlite3_close (conn);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: func1 is not going to update the str pointer.  You need to call it like `void func1(char **str)`.  Also, you are calling realloc wrong.  If it fails and returns null, you have lost whatever was in str before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change func1 to correctly update the passed in pointer.  Something like this:

```
void func1 (char **str)
{
    char str2[3000];
    char *tmp = NULL;
    strcpy (str2, "...");

    tmp = (char*) realloc (*str, sizeof (char) * (strlen (str2) * 2));
    if (!tmp) {
        *str = tmp;
    }
    strcat (*str, str2);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You are mallocing sizeof char which is 1 byte. malloc sizeof char * 3001